# Running ESLint in precommit does not stop on warnings

Tags: javascript, eslint, husky

I'm adding some precommit and prepush scripts to my project. I'm using Husky because it keeps tracked on git any change.

On my package.json I have:

```
"precommit": "npm run lint && npm run test",
```

Which initially seems to be working fine, when any test or lint **error** was found I was unable to make the commit.

Now I found that if I have a warning, the commit happens anyway.

How can I configure Husky, or maybe ESLint, to stop the commit when there are warnings?

I know I could override all eslint configs to be always error [2], but I'm expecting there is something better

Comment: any solutions so far?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You need specify `--max-warnings` param.

Something like this:

```
"scripts": {
  ...
  "lint": "eslint \"**/*.js\" --max-warnings=0",
  ...
},
```

Comment: very nice. saves time.

Comment: I would recommend **not** running `--fix` in a pre-commit scenario, because if it fixes something the linting will pass but those fixes will be unstaged (and therefore won't be included in the commit).

Comment: @jonrsharpe Not if you use lint-staged

Answer (score 0):

"eslint --cache --max-warnings=-1"  ignore all eslint warnings

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade **lint-staged** to version 15.1 or above.
Now it suppress some warnings when using the "--quiet" flag.

But still, you have to manually fix the errors.