# How to trigger fail CI/CD on eslint warning

Tags: gitlab, eslint

I would like to trigger fail CI/CD gitlab job on eslint warnings.

Eslint will fail on error, but in CI/CD I would like to fail on warnings too.

How can I do it?

Comment: Either change your rules to apply them as error instead of warning, or set `--max-warnings 0`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running ESLint in precommit does not stop on warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51158815/husky-running-eslint-in-precommit-does-not-stop-on-warnings)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can fail eslint on any warnings by adding the `--max-warnings=0` flag. For example:

```
eslint '**/*.js' --max-warnings=0
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `eslint-plugin-only-error` to convert all your warnings to errors